# Is there any criterion for hibernate criteria to cover contains condition of list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My question is that, I have a class like:

```
@Entity
public class Product{
@Id
String id;
String name;
@ManyToMany
List<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity
public class Tag{
@Id
String id;
String name;
}
```

I want to search products with criteria like in but reversive as:

```
session.createCriteria(Product.class).add(
    Restrictions.and(
        Restrictions.like("name",name+"%"),
        Restrictions.contains("tags",tag)).list();
```

But obviously Restrictions.contains does not exist. I only can find solutions with HQL queries but I don't want to (actually can't) write HQL queries.

Is there any way to handle this with criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just join the association using `createAlias` et do a simple compare:

```
session.createCriteria(Product.class)
    .createAlias("tags", "tag")
    .add( Restrictions.eq("tag", tag))
    .list()
```

Comment: alias is worked as expected, except it gives error when i use your code, but when i write as .add(Restrictions.eq("tag.id",tag.getId()) it worked

Comment: I have the same code as you @bdogru but when hibernate return the tag list, it contains only the one with the id in the condition, all other tags are not there, do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you are in search of [Restrictions.in(String propertyName, Collection values)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)? In the chapter **15.2. Narrowing the result set** you will find an example:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("name", new String[] { "Fritz", "Izi", "Pk" })))
    .add(Restrictions.disjunction())
    .list();
```

Comment: No, I am in search of just the opposite of "Restrictions.in". I know what is and how to know it.

Comment: I added a Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("name", new String[] { "Fritz", "Izi", "Pk" }))

Comment: It is obvious that I coulnd't made my point. My domain product has a tag list, I want to get all products that has tagList which contains a the tag.